# Automated Install of PADS (Mentor Graphics) works manually but not in Software Center

Tags: batch, automated-install

I am trying to automate the install of PADS VX.2 or PADS VX.2.2 (made by Mentor Graphics) to be ran with Software Center. It has a proprietary batch tool that I used to make a silent install script, and it runs fine when I call it through an admin power shell or command prompt.

After I distributed it to our servers and ran the install through Software Center, however, a pop up comes up saying there was an error running Dave Navigator (not sure what that is).

It seems like it happens during the post-install scripts that are made by the program. If I click OK and let it finish, then try to run Hyper-lynx DRC I get a pop up saying that PADS Flow is not working/ installed or something to that extent (I probably should have taken a screen shot of that).

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Maybe that Software Center runs the script as SYSTEM or something similar? So far I haven't been able to fix it.

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGBLV.png)